# Resizing a kendo drop-down

Tags: javascript, html, css, kendo-ui, telerik

I have a kendo dropdown which I have to resize but for some reason it does not work. It shows the icon but does not resize the container.

**Html**:

```
<select id="dropdownlist">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList();
```

**CSS**

```
 .k-list-container {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

It works for any other control besides dropdown.
Can anybody point me in the right direction please?

http://jsfiddle.net/bWs9j/389/

Comment: Does it support resizing?

Comment: As far as I know yes.. You can set default width/height.

Comment: Are you sure? I can't see a resize option in [their API reference](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist).

Comment: Oh.. is there some workaround?

Comment: I don't see .k-list-container in your markup. Maybe you mean .k-dropdown-wrap?

Comment: K-list-container shows up in mark-up when you open the drop-down list.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
  $("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList().data("kendoDropDownList");

  var dragging = false,
    currentX = null,
    currentW = null;

  $("body")
    .on("mousedown", ".k-dropdown-wrap", function(e) {
      dragging = true;
      currentX = e.clientX;
      currentW = $(this).width();
    })
    .on("mouseup", ".k-dropdown-wrap", function() {
      dragging = false;
    })
    .on("mousemove", function(e) {
      if (dragging) {
        var diff = currentX - e.clientX,
                wrapper = $($("#dropdownlist").data("kendoDropDownList").wrapper);

        wrapper.width((currentW - diff) + 20);
      }
    })
    .on("mouseup blur focusout", function() {
      dragging = false;
    });
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bWs9j/397/)

There are a few little gliches yet but I think you can work them up as you wish, as well wrap it into a jQuery component if you like.

Comment: Thanks, it works, however, I would like to resize the list of options instead of the dropdown itself.

Comment: @DavisZ well, I'm sorry but it doesn't makes sense to me. Have you any example, of any kind of this feature? Never seem a dropdown/combobox with resizable list.